# Angular 7 : issues while installing igniteui-angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to install igniteui-angular package but I'm getting those errors:

```
 Installing packages for tooling via npm.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency web-animations-js@^2.3.1 included from igniteui-angular will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Yess consulting\\WorkflowTemplate\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--quiet" "igniteui-angular@7.3.20"
npm ERR! node v12.15.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/animations@7.2.16 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/material@7.3.7 wants @angular/animations@>=7.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular-calendar@0.22.3 wants @angular/animations@>=4.0.0 <6.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer igniteui-angular@7.3.20 wants @angular/animations@^7.0.3

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     \npm-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
Package install failed, see above.
```

`package.json`:

---

```
{
      "name": "test",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
        "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
        "@angular/common": "^7.2.7",
        "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^7.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^7.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "^7.0.0",
        "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^7.0.0",
        "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^3.0.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.9.0",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.3.1",
        "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.16.0",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.1",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
        "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^13.0.0",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons": "^17.4.43",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-diagrams": "^17.3.29",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids": "^17.3.29",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-inputs": "^17.3.29",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-navigations": "^17.3.27",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-popups": "^17.3.29",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-splitbuttons": "^17.3.27",
        "@types/datatables.net": "1.10.9",
        "angular-calendar": "^0.22.1",
        "angular-collapse": "0.0.5",
        "angular-datatables": "6.0.0",
        "bn-ng-idle": "^1.0.1",
        "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
        "chartist": "^0.11.0",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "datatables.net": "2.1.1",
        "datatables.net-buttons": "2.2.0",
        "datatables.net-buttons-bs4": "^1.6.1",
        "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^2.2.0",
        "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.20",
        "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.2.3",
        "datatables.net-responsive-dt": "^2.2.3",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "fontawesome": "^5.6.3",
        "grid-component": "^0.11.1",
        "igniteui-cli": "^5.0.1",
        "jasmine": "^3.1.0",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "latest": "^0.2.0",
        "ng-chartist": "^1.1.1",
        "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
        "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
        "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
        "ng2-smart-table": "^1.2.2",
        "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^4.3.0",
        "ngx-color-picker": "^8.0.1",
        "ngx-icon-picker": "0.0.10",
        "ngx-pagination": "^4.1.0",
        "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^5.0.0",
        "ngx-quill": "^3.1.0",
        "ngx-select-ex": "^3.7.2",
        "ngx-translate-multi-http-loader": "^2.1.2",
        "popper.js": "^1.12.5",
        "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
        "save": "^2.4.0",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
        "@angular/cli": "^7.0.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.0",
        "@types/chartist": "^0.9.37",
        "@types/datatables.net-buttons": "^1.4.3",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
        "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "^4.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "^5.4.1",
        "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
        "tslint": "~5.7.0",
        "typescript": "3.2.4"
      }
    }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The conflicts can arise out of global installations of the package and not local installations ...

My gospel with this stuff is to Stop all software.  Go to command line. Remove all globals npm package installations, Go to app folder and delete node_modules.  Then npm install (npm shrink wrap if you do that... regenerate vendor/client js... ) etc.

The look at the version errors, update and a adjust accordingly.